# How to group by in laravel with related table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is my blade file

```
<ul>
@foreach ($cajeros as $cajero)
<li>
    {{$cajero->idcajero}}
    <ul>
        @foreach ($cajero->conciliaciones as $conciliacion)                        
            <li>Lote {{ $conciliacion->lote }} - ${{ $conciliacion->importe_comisionable }}</li>
        @endforeach
        Total cajero: ${{ $cajero->conciliaciones->sum('importe_comisionable') }}
    </ul>
</li>
@endforeach
```

And this is the result

[image]

What I want to do is group by lote and get the sum of that.
I tried doing

```
        @foreach ($cajero->conciliaciones->groupby('lote') as $key => $conciliaciones)                
            <li>Lote {{ $key }} - ${{ sum($conciliaciones) }}</li>
        @endforeach
```

and I got

> Call to undefined function sum()

Also, I tried doing it on the controller. But I get the sum as zero.

```
$detalle = [];
    foreach ($cajeros as $cajero){
        $detalle[] = [$cajero->id => $cajero->conciliaciones->groupby('lote')->sum('importe_comisionable')];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

```
<ul>
@foreach ($cajeros as $cajero)
<li>
    {{$cajero->idcajero}}
    <ul>
        @foreach ($cajero->conciliaciones->groupby('lote') as $key => $conciliaciones)
            @php $suma = 0; @endphp
            @foreach ($conciliaciones as $conciliacion)
                @php $suma += $conciliacion->importe_comisionable; @endphp
            @endforeach
            <li>Lote {{ $key }} - ${{ $suma }}</li>
        @endforeach
        Total cajero: ${{ $cajero->conciliaciones->sum('importe_comisionable') }}
    </ul>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).